# Decompress .deflate files as text in HDFS and copy result to local

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, deflate

After running a sqoop jobs I got the files `.deflate` extension (compression is configured by default). I know that I can show the file content using following command:

```
hadoop fs -text  <file>
```

How can I copy this result to my local folder?

Answer (score 8):

Just redirect output to some local file

```
hadoop fs -text hdfs_path > local_file.txt
```